# IE always opens with random local host and message: "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server"

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, ie8

I have my WebDriver tests running parallel in IE, Chrome and firefox. When I run test in IE browser it node gets registered with the hub, and the browser opens and it gets redirected to some random localhost and it gives the message:

> This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server.

I'm running my script on Secured Browser, I tried with all the way's:

```
setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING, true);
setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.NATIVE_EVENTS, false);
setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL, "");
```

But still I am getting this is in the initial start page of browser error it was not Executing or Failing.

```
All zoom setting in IE was 100%
protected mode was on.
```

please help me what could be the problem and possible work around.

```
platform:Windows XP, IE8 browser
```

The same is running well in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Doing a Google reveals several possible options - have you tried doing a search and looking at the replies ? Do any of them apply to your situation ?

Comment: What do you mean by "random localhost"?

Comment: I believe this is normal, is this somehow impeding your testing?

Answer (score 3):

This is as designed, so there is nothing to worry about. You can then start opening your website using `driver.Navigate().GoToURL()` method.

Answer (score 1):

In IE, this will usually show as the default page at the start of a test, until you provide it with a valid URL to navigate to.

Especially if you attempt to do something to the present (empty) page, it may cause an exception or problem - for example, [trying to maximise the window with javascript causing this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8490622/175051).

The first thing your test should do is navigate to a valid page, and then things should work smoothly at that point.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue occurs when you didn't configure IE properly according to manual:
[InternetExplorer configuration](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration)
Make sure:

1. Zoom is set to 100%
2. Protected Mode settings for each zone have the same value

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
 DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
 caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL, "");
 WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
```