# Running application doesn't execute any code but opens a new window

Tags: selenium, webdriver, java, selenium-webdriver, eclipse

I am trying a build an automated testing framework, using Selenium WebDriver to simply login a website.

However, when I run the following code, the only thing that happens is a new internet explorer window pops up stating "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server."

My code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;


public class WebSeleniumClient {

    public static void main(String[] args){

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Picheal\\Desktop\\Selenium Web Driver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath()); 

    // Creates InternetExplorer Driver 

    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); 

    //Opens Login
    for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i++){
    driver.get("https://ams2.enoah.com/Home/Login?returnurl=%2f");
    System.out.println(i);
    }



    // Finds login form and inputs credentials 
    WebElement user  = driver.findElement(By.id("dnn_ctr780_Login_Login_JLSystems.NOAH_txtUsername"));
    WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.id("dnn_ctr780_Login_Login_JLSystems.NOAH_txtPassword"));

    user.sendKeys("********"); 
    pass.sendKeys("********"); 
}
```

}

My console looks like:

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.47.0.0
Listening on port 63771
```

I usually don't ask questions but this is a just strange behavior. I believe this may be an error in eclipse. I deleted all my code, saved, and ran the same again, and still I got the same result - a new internet explorer window only.

Comment: duplicate of http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3513/ie-always-opens-with-random-local-host-and-msgthis-is-the-initial-start-page-f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the IE versions, your machine should be having both IE versions i.e. 32-bit and 64-bit and when you start the 'IEDriverServer.exe' it calls the 64-bit IE version while you are using 32-bit IEDriverServer.exe. I faced this issue too and observed that when any tool starts IE then 64-bit IE is launched by default (I was on Windows 7 and IE-9), because they pick default settings of the system which is usually 64-bit.

So either make 32-bit Internet Explorer default or download the 64-bit IEDriverServer.exe from [Selenium Downloads](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) and use the same.

For making 32-bit IE as default refer this link [32-bit Default IE](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-default-browser-to-32bit/bd51a9b1-7216-4fa6-acbd-696b04981da4?auth=1)

Answer (score 0):

If test is running successfully on other browser then there is configuration issue of IE on machine.

Make sure version of Selenium, IE driver and IE browser are compatible  [Ref. selenium release log](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG)

Also verify required configure mentioned [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration)

Answer (score -1):

`user.sendkeys("""")` won't work because type WebElement does not allow string arguments.

Other than that this works perfect in my system (Win7 64 bit).

You can try:

1. Check the versions of your Eclipse and IEDriver to check whether they are 32/64 bit as others have said here.
2. Try using Capabilities class for your IEDriver.

Comment: why the down vote? is it because I havent typed it ''neatly''. lol..this community. I am so tired.

Comment: All I missed was some spaces, i think.  I am no longer going to post anything until i feel its abs necessary

Comment: You haven't really explained how the Capabilities class will help the poster. I've cleaned up your format and grammar a bit to make your answer a bit easier to understand, but you really need to show how your suggestions will help: indicate what the OP should be doing instead of `WebElement.SendKeys("*****")` and give an example of using the Capabilities class.